# discord.py breaks python error-checking, including syntax errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, discord, discord.py

I recently started working on a simple discord bot using discord.py. I suspect my problem may have something to do with async programming, since I have no prior experience with async, so I don't know what is going on too well.
My problem is this: inside the body of a command function, any simple error will not visibly raise anything. For example:

```
async def send_ttt_board(ctx, mat):
    o_player, x_player = client.get_user(match['roles']['O']), client.get_user(match['roles']['X'])
    ...
```

the argument name is `mat`, but in the block `match` is used twice. Normally, this should obviously raise a SyntaxError, but for me, this doesn't happen. When the bot is run, no error is raised, and the command that calls this function doesn't work. All unrelated commands don't work.